# Rename Entity and all references

Tags: c#, entity-framework, refactoring

I use Entity framework Model First. I use Model Designer. How can I rename entity class name and all references (from curent project and from dependet project)? Also how to rename properties names?

Comment: You can edit the EDMX file in a text editor if you know what you're doing. I don't know what you mean by this "dependent project".

Comment: If i rename entity in model, designer generate new class. But another code where i use entity will be use old name. All code is broken. I can use tool 'Find and replace', but i whant do it automated. Like rename class tool